# Upsert in DB2 with php parameters

Tags: sql, db2, upsert

I have a working insert going into DB2, using PHP parameters in a script. It works perfectly but I'm trying to fix it up so that I don't have to truncate and rebuild every time. I'd like to simply update my last 2 fields if my unique key fields already exist.

The insert:

```
INSERT INTO testSchema.metrics (cust, item, material, color, group, group2, sales, score )
    VALUES (
        :cust_id, 
        :item,
        :material,
        :color,
        :group,
        :group2,
        :sales,
        :score
    )
```

I do have a new Unique Key Constraint on cust_id, item, material and color. I simply want to say "If a record exists for this customer, item, material and color, update sales and score"

I realized I can't do a traditional upsert here, but is there something in DB2 that would be best suited for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try a `MERGE` statement to conditionally `INSERT` or `UPDATE` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html

Comment: So when the examples state that you merge 'ON' values, would I put all 4 columns that make up my unique constraint?

Comment: Yes, that would be the logical thing to do. `MERGE` needs only one row to match. >  "Each row in the target can only be operated on once. A row in the target can only be identified as MATCHED with one row in the result table of the table-reference"